# Identify private or public ssh key

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, ssh-keys

I have few keys in `~/.ssh` directory. I need to identify whether the files in this directory is private key or public key without depending on the `.pub` extension (because keys could be renamed and used).

I tried `ssh-keygen -lf <priv key>` but it prints the details same as for public key.

```
# diff <(ssh-keygen -lf id_rsa) <(ssh-keygen -lf id_rsa.pub)
#
```

Same result when i tried `ssh-keygen -ef` in the above mentioned command.

Is there a better way to find whether the key is private or public instead of `cat <key> | grep -i public`?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're only interested in keys compatible with OpenSSH, if it starts with `----` (four ASCII hyphens) then you can say it's a private key.

#### Private key headers

Private keys in the "new" OpenSSH format start with:

- `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`

Private keys in the PEM and PKCS#8 formats start with one of the following:

- `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
- `-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
- `-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----`
- `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`
- `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`
- (PKCS#8 keys can also be binary DER, but that's uncommon.)

Private keys in the PuTTY 'PPK' format (used mostly on Windows) start with:

- `PuTTY-User-Key-File-2:`

Private keys in the SSH.COM format (used on some non-Linux operating systems) start with:

- `---- BEGIN SSH2 ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY ----`

  (Note four dashes and a space, instead of five dashes.)

#### Public key headers

Public keys in the OpenSSH one-line format **do not** have a fixed header. (They start with the key format, which *does not* always start with `ssh-` or `ecdsa-`.) But they can be reliably detected after Base64-decoding the 2nd field, as it contains an exact duplicate of the key type from the 1st field.

On the other hand, if you're examining the files directly, you can easily tell it's an OpenSSH .pub file just by looking and recognizing the general shape:

1. an OpenSSH .pub file has everything in a single, very long line;
2. the first field is the key type;
3. the second field is the Base64-encoded public data, practically always beginning with `AAAA`.

The other formats listed below are just for general interest – you won't find them under ~/.ssh/:

Public keys in the PEM and PKCS#8 formats (which is a combination that's almost never used with OpenSSH) start with one of the following:

- `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`
- `-----BEGIN DSA PUBLIC KEY-----`
- `-----BEGIN EC PUBLIC KEY-----`
- `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`
- Keys can also come in binary DER format, but that's even less common.

Public keys in the SSH.COM (RFC 4716) format start with:

- `---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----`

  (Note four dashes and a space, instead of five dashes.)

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of this method of `grep` for strings. I was trying to find whether there is a command somewhat like `ssh-keygen -lf` which will say this is a private/public key.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't one which could do so reliably.